# regex to match string but not substring

Tags: regex

I have this regex `/\$([^:\n]+)/` and the following strings

1. `gid$gid::`
2. `$gid::`
3. `::$gid`
4. `bar$:$gid:f$oo`

currently [running the regex on each string independently](https://regex101.com/r/eAV934/1), I get these matches

1. `gid`
2. `gid`
3. `gid`
4. [`gid`, `oo`]

I need to alter the regex so there are no matches in number 1 and only one match in number 4 - the middle `$gid`. In other words, it only matches strings starting with `$` that **start at the beginning** of the string or **immediately after a colon**.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using (php)

```php
preg_match_all('/(^|:)\$(\w+)/m', $subject, $matches);
```

the `m` options and the implied `g` options (by `_all` in the function) were key to getting the answer I needed.

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/v35

Answer (score 1):

You may find other examples that further restrict what you need, but this seems to work as you describe:

```
(^|:)(\$[^:\n]+)
```

Working here https://regex101.com/r/HGtNw1/1

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction, but I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working fully in php for me. The reason was that I wasn't using `preg_match_all` with the `m` option. At regex101, both the `g` and `m` flags are enabled by default so the behavior was different.

Comment: That makes sense, although I answered the question from a regex point of view, it wasn't tagged `php` - passing in the flags, php would be the same. Although I notice from the answer you posted yourself you apparently also have additional restrictions on the characters allowed, which weren't apparent from the question (`\w`). At any rate, please accept a given answer as the answer, to close the question.